# select distinct not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

Student group table:

```
STDNT_GROUP

studentId,CollegeID,studentgroup,flag
1,007,panthers,y
2,003,owls,n
3,007,owls,y
1,007,texans,y
2,003,texans,n
```

Expected output

```
1,007
2,003
3,007
```

I want unique student ids as well as their respective college ids.

I tried this query:

```
select distinct(studentId),collegeID from;
```

and

```
select studentId,collegeID from STDNT_GROUP where studentId in(select distinct(studentId) from STDNT_GROUP)";
```

Comment: More familiar with tSQL but does `select studentId, collegeID from STDNT_GROUP group by studentId` work?

Comment: Parentheses or not, the query `SELECT DISTINCT studentId, CollegeID FROM STDNT_GROUP` should work the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT` without parentheses should get you what you want.   `DISTINCT` should be thought of as a clause, rather than a function to which you pass a column name as an argument.  It returns the set of distinct *rows* over the superset returned by the query, rather than distinct values in a single column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  studentId,
  CollegeID
FROM STUDENT_GROUP
```

Comment: Yeah i got some output. Actually the number of rows i get are huge.Is there a way to check if i am getting unique values?

Comment: Don't trust the database, eh?  Well, if any of the rows in your result set *weren't* unique, then `SELECT studentid , collegeid , COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT studentId, CollegeID FROM STUDENT_GROUP ) GROUP BY studentid , collegeid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;` would return some rows.

Comment: @Michael: I have no Oracle handy to test, but I don't see any reason for the query not to work (exactly the same) with parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this for unsorted results:

```
select distinct studentid, collegeid from stdnt_group
```

Or this:

```
select studentid, collegeid from stdnt_group
group by studentid, collegeid
```

Or you could add an order by clause to any of them to retrieve them in order:

```
[previous query]
order by studentid, collegeid
```

Comment: sorted results would be `select distinct studentId, collegId from stdnt_group order by studentId, collegeId` or  `select studentId, collegeId from stdnt_group group by studentId, collegeId order by studentId, collegeId`. Without `order by` the results may or may not be sorted.

Comment: Any reference for the claim that `DISTINCT` does not sort while `GROUP BY` sorts results?

Comment: My bad, missed the order by. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be your use of paranthesis in the distinct call. Try just:

```
      SELECT DISTINCT studentID, collegeID
```

It may be helpful to provide what output you are actually getting as opposed to just the expected output. That may help us better determine whatmay be going wrong.